# How can I map by multiple parameters as keys in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

In my specific case, I wanna automatically cache modified images - my program does some computer vision. For that, it often resamples images to decrease resolution. This speeds up the recognition while having little (if any) impact on my algorithm precision. But this is a general question.

I want to have a hash map that contains multiple keys for one value. Like this:

```
//Map images by width and height
protected HashMap<(Integer, Integer), BufferedImage> resampled_images;
```

Of course, syntax above is invalid. A shitty way go around that would be to concatenate parameters to string:

```
protected HashMap<String, BufferedImage> resampled_images;
...
//Some function that resamples and caches the resampled versions
public BufferedImages getResampled(int new_width, int new_height, boolean cache) {
  ...
  resampled_images.put(new_width+"X"+new_height, resampled_me);
}
```

With just integer the parameters I think it would work nice. But there are cases I'd need to index by more complex structures - and mostly it would again be caching function results. Image processing is very CPU expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a `Pair<A,B>` class:

```
class Pair<A,B>{
    A first;
    B second;
}
```

then create a `HashMap<Pair<Integer,Integer>,BufferedImage>` .

EDIT:

In your special case the easiest way to implement it would be with primitives types (int). You could also implement the `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` methods, so that the HashMap can use them.

```
public class Pair{
    int x,y;

    public Pair(int x,int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return ((x + y) << 234234) % 21354205;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof Pair){
            Pair p = (Pair) o;
            return p.x == x && p.y == y;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

the `hashCode()` method is generated with eclipse.

Comment: Yes, this is something I'd really like to do! But how would actually the HashMap compare my `Pair` instances?

Comment: ill edit the answer and add some more specific stuff ;)

Comment: Thaknk you a lot, I'm definitelly going to use this. I accepted your answer already, but could you annotate the `hashCode` method? The magic with `prime` and bitshifting isn't quite clear to me.

Comment: the hash function should spread the values uniformally so that the possibility of collisions is very low. a good way to do that is by scattering the values randomly. these shifts and primes are a good way to emulate a "random" distribution. try wikipedia if you want to know more ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following scheme.

```
Map<height, width> m1;
Map<width, BufferedImage> m2;
```

Allows you to create key aliases.

That way I believe you can have a value (BufferedImage), associated with multiple keys like height and width here.

To put BufferedImage use,

```
m1.put(height,width);
m2.put(width, BufferedImage);
```

To get BufferedImage use,

```
m2.get(m1.get(height));
```

Comment: Could you explain more? I don't know where does it aim.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
You could use a `java.awt.Dimension` object (or another object of you definition) to store both height and width;

```
protected HashMap<Dimension, BufferedImage> resampled_images;
```

ex:

```
resampled_images.put(new Dimension(width, height), image);
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make much sense. `k1` and `k2` represent width and height - you can't just swap them.